# Using a license.licx file with an F# script?

Tags: .net, f#, embedded-resource, f#-interactive

We have a library written in C# that I'm trying to call within an F# script. However, this library uses dotConnect for MySQL from DevArt which requires that the program using it has a particular line in a licenses.licx file embedded into the assembly.

Anyone have an idea of how I can get FSI to know about this license?

Comment: This is only a guess -- but you might be able to add some code to the beginning of your script to load the license into FSI via [System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.licensemanager.aspx "System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager").

Answer (score 3):

Does the `.licx` file has to be embedded in the program (`.exe`) that calls the library, or could it be embedded in another library that calls dotConnect and is called by `fsi.exe`?

- In the second case, you could just create a simple wrapper that calls the dotConnect's functionality you need and call the wrapper from `fsi.exe`.
- In the first case, you could either recompile `fsi.exe` (as suggested by John).

  An easier approach might be to create a separate application (containing the `licx` file) that loads `fsi.exe` assembly using Reflection and then use Reflection to start the `fsi.exe` interaction loop
  (I think you could just invoke static method `MainMain` of `Shell` class in `Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive`).

Comment: The library I'm calling already has the license embedded, so it's the first case. I'll try your suggestions and see how it goes. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

F# is open source - there is a version up here https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/.  Could you just build your own version of FSI with your license file?

Comment: Thanks, I might try this and see how it goes. The link you sent says it's for Mono, does that matter? I'm on Windows

Comment: That link should build fine on .Net  there is also the code drops at http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/ which include the compiler and fsi